# Ubuntu 20.04 File, right-click directory, Open in Terminal (NEW tab)

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

Using Ubuntu 20.04, select a directory, right-click. There is an option "Open in Terminal"

Is there a way to open in a new tab?

- if there is no terminal, then open in new terminal
- if there is already an existing terminal, then open the dir in a new tab

[image]